# My visual studio 2010 install suffers severe performance problems, what approaches can I take to find out the cause?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, performance

I'm using VS2010, and hitting severe performance problems. For example I can load up, create a 'HelloWorld' project, start to debug it, and VS is using 700MB of RAM, and behaving sluggishly whenever I start to type.

Now, given the sparse information I've provided, theres no way I expect the exact cause of the problem I'm having to be given. Instead, I'll ask for some **general ways to find out the cause of VS performance issues**.

For example:

Does VS keep some form of cache from previous sessions which is loaded every startup? Where does this live if so?

Are Extensions commonly a problem? Are there any tools to show separate memory/CPU usage of each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

700MB Ram is really no big deal. Really. Not keeping up with your typing is, though.

To diagnose this, try disabling or removing any and all add-ins... things like re-sharper, source control plug-ins, etc, and then re-enable them one at a time until you find which one(s) make it slow.